# Putting an array in to a table ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got a response back from an API which contains a list of hotels, which I want to store in an array and then display this list in a table, something like this.

```
//Get a response
IRestResponse<RootObject> searchResponse = client.Execute<RootObject>(searchRequest);

var hotelList = searchResponse.Data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary.ToArray();

foreach (var hotelSummary in hotelList.ToArray())
{
    TextBoxResults.Text = hotelSummary.hotelId.ToString();
    TextBoxResults.Text = hotelSummary.shortDescription.ToString();
    TextBoxResults.Text = hotelSummary.address1.ToString();
    TextBoxResults.Text = hotelSummary.address2.ToString();
    TextBoxResults.Text = hotelSummary.city.ToString();
}
```

At the moment, what this is doing is only returning one of the ten results from the list of results and not all 10.

What I'm trying to do is put the list into an array and then display the results in a table in my ASP.net page, the list will not contain more than ten results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've chosen the wrong Control to show your data. Textbox can only show 1 value not a list of values. I guess you are using forms. then you have grid view.
use it like this:

```
MyGridview.DataSource = hotelList ;
MyGridview.DataBind();
```

Take a look at [this link](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data) from asp.net

---

### Update

also take a look at this
[C# - Populating Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454910/c-sharp-populating-gridview)

Comment: I'm using web pages aspx.

Comment: @Rickshaw I know, it is called web forms and we also have MVC.

Comment: Thanks buddy, will take a look in to the link.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it's happening is because you're just overwriting the `TextBoxResults`. Seems like you don't have a Datagridview or some sort.

Answer (score 0):

So I used the following as suggested:

```
//Get a response
                IRestResponse<RootObject> searchResponse = client.Execute<RootObject>(searchRequest);

                var hotelList = searchResponse.Data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary.ToArray();

                foreach (var hotelSummary in hotelList.ToArray())
                {
                    GridViewResults.DataSource = hotelList;
                    GridViewResults.DataBind();
                }
```

This returns everything, and opens up the list and all the element provided from the API, it would be good to return only certain columns, instead of all of them.